# Custom radio group is not working in Marshmallow

Tags: android, radio-group

I've multiple radio button and to place radio button at desired location I've to wrap these radio button in different Layouts like linear and relative so wrapping these layouts under radio group wouldn't surve the purpose and for that I've t write the custom RadioGroup.

As the behavior of radio group user can only select one radio button at time. I've tested in Lollipop and Marshmallow it's not behaving correctly in Marshmallow (user can select multiple radio button)

Here is the code.

```
public class AgentRadioGroup extends RadioGroup
{
    private static final String TAG = "AgentRadioGroup";

    public AgentRadioGroup(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public AgentRadioGroup(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewAdded(View child) {
        if( child instanceof ViewGroup)
        {
            ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) child;
            for(int i=0; i<viewGroup.getChildCount(); i++)
            {
                View subChild = viewGroup.getChildAt(i);
                if( subChild instanceof ViewGroup )
                {
                    onViewAdded(subChild);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (subChild instanceof RadioButton) {
                        super.onViewAdded(subChild);
                        Log.d(TAG, "Radio button added!");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (child instanceof RadioButton)
        {
            super.onViewAdded(child);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Elabroate, please on which way it doesn't work. Does it look wrong? Or your app is crashing? Thanks,

Comment: it's not behaving as the radio group behaves allow only one selection at the time but in M I'm able to select all the radio button at the same time